# Angular: Get NgForm in the projected content

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

Let us say I have a component like below:

```html
<app-my-typical-form>
  <app-child-in-content></app-child-in-content>
</app-my-typical-form>
```

where `my-typical-form.component.html` is:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
<hr>
<h3>Here is my form from the parent:</h3>
{{f|json}}
```

and `child-in-content.component.html` and `child-in-content.component.ts` are as follow:

```html
<h2>
  My Form from the projected content is:
</h2>
<br>
{{myForm|json}}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-in-content',
  templateUrl: './child-in-content.component.html',
})
export class ChildInContentComponent {
  constructor(@Optional() public myForm: NgForm) { }
}
```

As you can see here in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcxhvs), `myForm` in `app-child-in-content` is null. However, my understanding is that since `child-in-content` is (kind) of child of `NgForm` I can have it via DI. That is apparently not working because of the content projection.

So, is there a way to get NgForm in `app-child-in-content` component (**EDIT**: before `ViewInit`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your forked [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zs3uyb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

First you need reference of NgForm using @ViewChild() decorator.

Your App.Component.ts is...

```
@ViewChild(ChildInContentComponent, {static:true})
    private wizardComponent: ChildInContentComponent;
    @ViewChild(MyTypicalFormComponent, {static:true})
    private TypicalForm: MyTypicalFormComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.wizardComponent.myForm = this.TypicalForm.wizardComponent      
}
```

Your typicalForm.component.ts add this...

```
@ViewChild('f', {static:true}) wizardComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this way `myForm` in `ChildInContentComponent` will be available only after `ViewInit`.